# How can I lazy load specific elements of a JSON file efficiently with GSON?

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, gson

I have a JSON file that is marshalled into custom object using GSON.
All works fine.
An example of the structure I have:

```
public class Domain {    
   private String id;  
   private String name;  
   //other fields  
   private ArrayList<Structures> structs;  
   private ArrayList<Buildings> buildings;   
   private ArrayList<CustomObject> objects;  
   // some more lists and fields  
}
```

So basically I create a builder and parse the json

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();  
gson.fromJson(jsonString, Domain.class);
```

This works absolutely fine. Parsing is done and I get my data.

**Problem:**
I don't really need to have various fields of the `Domain` class populated from the start because e.g. I may have the Domain class with a lot of elements in the e.g. list for `structs` but I might not really need to access them.
What I need to do is some kind of pattern for lazy loading.
I.e. I would like to **not** load some parts of class during the json parsing and only load them when needed.

**Question:**
If I understand correctly the way to skip fields from being parsed is by making them transient.
But then if at some later time I need to access e.g. the `structs` how would I actually load them at that point? I think that reloading/reparsing all the json again is suboptimal.

What is a standard/good approach for this?

Comment: I'm not suggesting or answering but I'm Chris to know what else is the advantage of lazy loading other than having the object with only fields that are required?  Memory?

Comment: @cgr:Yes exactly. Avoid having a bunch of data in memory that I might not eventually access

Answer (score 2):

This is a really lengthy topic. There are many approaches to this and all of them are usually a lot more complicated. The easiest one, if you really value something very simple for me was so far not using gson, but for example something like JSONObject and then populate the object myself. using this you could easily split this up into multiple steps. The problem that now arises is, that you never know, what exactly is already loaded - or more - what is maybe loaded, but just not filled as a field.

Lazy loading using automatic conversions like gson is unfortunately always gonna involve unnecessary object creation too, so question then is if its not less pain just to do it yourself from the beginning.

if it has to be gson, you could have different objects for different stages. read them in through json and then apply to your main object.

a favourable version of that is probably to split up the object into different components (or aspects or whatever you want to call it) that match the different loading stages. Different possibilities but lets just pick one of them:

```
class Domain {
    private String id;
    private DomainStructs domainStructs;
}

class DomainStructs {
    private ArrayList<Structures> structs;  
}
```

Now you need a new Object in this version of doing this. This means the overall size of the model is slightly (but not much really) bigger and you should probably match together things that are necessary together anyway - so not load every field separate, but this way you can leave out parts and easily add them later by populating them from Gson like 2 steps here:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();  
Domain domain = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Domain.class);  // first time

domain.structs = gson.fromJson(jsonString, DomainStructs.class); // now adding
```

I am not saying this is the best idea ever, but it fulfills your idea while still using gson.

I would though consider splitting up the Data already - so not storing the strings, but holding the data in different components in this case if it is possible. Basically you want a domainJsonString and a domainStructsJsonString if you get what i mean. stored in a way so you can easily retrieve them separately.

I hope this helps you to move a bit forward

Comment: I don't have a strict requirement to stick to GSON (if that does not offer any improvement in the change I am looking for). I do have a strict requirement to **not** change the JSON format. I think by the separation you suggest I would need to change the JSON. Also what is the most efficient approach then for my requirements?

Comment: This is a bit tricky. It depdends really on your memory usage, as first parsing the json document into a JSONObject (the other json api) also consumes memory. so if you really really want to save memory consider using multiple loading methods and this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html 
This would have the least memory impact. its a lot of code, but its quick and memory efficient. 
I would though strongly suggest changing the data structures ;)

Comment: If you mean change the JSON format that is out of my options (does not depend on me and I can not influence that part). I can only change the parsing. I would like to use less memory but it is not clear to me how much more code would be needed for something else? I assume that by using the JSONObject the document is parsed but no actual java classes would be instantiated so there is no memory overhead there except the initial parsing of the document. That doesn't sound bad, but I am not sure how to proceed as a start if I don't change the JSON. Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Well JSONObject actually creates objects for every node in the json. means everything that is a jsonobject or jsonarray in the document is an object. but also strings are objects. not sure about internal data structure, if ints are different but it doesnt really matter that much - in the end parsing a document into JSONObject is a *lot* of memory. The alternative is to use JsonReader which is a sax styled parser instead of dom. this one will not keep all the stuff in memory and is therefore very lightweight. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html is exactly that